# Visual component become invisible in design mode and cannot get them back in Fire Monkey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, monkey

I am using a TScaledLayout as a background and after I load the project a few times ALL visual components become invisible, they are there and will compile and run fine but I cannot get them to become visible again. Has happened 4 times now and have had to revert to a backup each time.

Comment: If you feel it is a bug , report it to the QC

Comment: Try diffing the failed DFM file with the working backup and see if there's an obvious cause.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered quite a few bugs in the IDE when using **Firemonkey** - it is nowhere near as reliable as **VCL** (yet).  In particular the `'.lfm'` and `'.pas'` can become unsynchronised, so that there are components in the `lfm`, which are defined not in the `pas` file.

This doesn't seem to affect runtime but sure can be confusing when you are coding...  Try checking to see that all of the components in the `lfm` are also defined on the `form`.  There also seems to a few issues surrounding form inheritance, where you just have to do a lot of things manually as changes to ancestors are often not picked up by descendants.

Also note that most Firemonkey components also now have a property called `'DesignVisible'`.  Check to see that this is set correctly.